# How to pass a function inside a function with Click in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
@main.command()
@click.option('--customer_safe_dns_name', '-c', type=str, help='The customer safe DNS name')
@click.option('--resource_choice', '-r', type=str, help='The resource type; cde or customer; to search workloads for.')
def get_workloads(customer_safe_dns_name, resource_choice):
            if resource_choice == 'cde':
                    workload_ids = [workload['Name'] for workload in all_workloads['Workloads']
                            if re.search(f'eks-.+{customer_safe_dns_name}-.+',
                                    workload['Name']) and workload['Status'] != 'DELETED']
                    return workload_ids
@main.command()
@click.pass_context
@click.option('--customer_safe_dns_name', '-c', type=str, help='The customer safe DNS name')
@click.option('--resource_choice', '-r', type=str, help='The resource type; cde or customer; to search workloads for.')
def delete_workloads(customer_safe_dns_name, resource_choice, ctx):
    ctx.forward(get_workloads)
    workloads_to_delete = ctx.invoke(get_workloads, customer_safe_dns_name=customer_safe_dns_name, resource_choice=resource_choice)
```

> `TypeError: delete_workloads() got multiple values for argument 'customer_safe_dns_name'`

Comment: If I don't use the context object and call the function straight, it treats each letter of the argument as an argument itself and throws a error, `Error: Got unexpected extra arguments (c u s t f a c t)`
```
@main.command()
@click.option('--customer_safe_dns_name', '-c', type=str, help='The customer safe DNS name')
@click.option('--resource_choice', '-r', type=str, help='The resource type; cde or customer; to search workloads for.')
def delete_workloads(customer_safe_dns_name, resource_choice):
    workloads_to_delete = get_workloads(customer_safe_dns_name, resource_choice)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new function that is called from `get_workloads` and `delete_workloads`:

```
@main.command()
@click.option('--customer_safe_dns_name', '-c', type=str, help='The customer safe DNS name')
@click.option('--resource_choice', '-r', type=str, help='The resource type; cde or customer; to search workloads for.')
def get_workloads(customer_safe_dns_name, resource_choice):
    return _handle_workload(resource_choice, customer_safe_dns_name)


@main.command()
@click.pass_context
@click.option('--customer_safe_dns_name', '-c', type=str, help='The customer safe DNS name')
@click.option('--resource_choice', '-r', type=str, help='The resource type; cde or customer; to search workloads for.')
def delete_workloads(customer_safe_dns_name, resource_choice):
    workloads_to_delete = _handle_workload(resource_choice, customer_safe_dns_name)


def _handle_workload(resource_choice, customer_safe_dns_name):
    workload_ids = []
    if resource_choice == 'cde':
        workload_ids = [workload['Name'] for workload in all_workloads['Workloads']
                        if re.search(f'eks-.+{customer_safe_dns_name}-.+',
                        workload['Name']) and workload['Status'] != 'DELETED']
    return workload_ids
```

Comment: Thank you @salparadise, I used ctx.invoke to get it working, I don't know why it wasn't working before.
`workloads_to_delete = ctx.invoke(get_workloads, customer_safe_dns_name=customer_safe_dns_name, resource_choice=resource_choice)`

Comment: Hey salparadise. Sorry I jumped on you on Code Review. Your answer can be good if you explain why you think `zip` is better. After reading your answer I do believe it's better than the OPs, I'm writing up my answer now, and basically came to the conclusion you did.

Comment: @Peilonrayz no problem. I will add some explanation.

Comment: Ping me once you're done and I'll change my downvote to an upvote asap